# What means this name for Jews Friends?

Tags: history, names

I wanna learn what does mean of "Hiram" name (I don't know Hebrew spelling of name).

I look up some sources for this name but I couldn't find enough info.

> 1) I wanna learn mean and importance of "Hiram" name for Jew Friends.
>
> 2) Who is he ?
>
> 3) Is "Hiram" important person in Judaism or not ?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Cheeram (with a guttural CH). http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/parsha/the-life-and-identity-of-chiram/2016/02/12/  http://www.tanach.org/shmot/truma/shiur2b.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chiram was the architect of the first Beis HaMikdash (Melachim Aleph 5-7), but he is also named as the builder of the City of David (Shmuel Beis 5:11) and Shlomo's palace (Melachim Aleph 9). As a son of a coppersmith and a descendant of Oholiav Ben Achisamach, the co-constructor of the Mishkan, through his mother, the Gemara uses him as a model that one should follow in his parents' footsteps in respect to career (Erchin 16b). In Hebrew his name is spelled חירם (Chiram), and sometimes חירום (Chirome).

Edit: I neglected to mention. He wasn't all that good; ultimately he declared himself to be a god. It was due to him and Nevuchadnezzar practicing self-deification that Hashem decreed death on the world (Bereishis Rabbah 9:5).

Answer (score 1):

[Here's his page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiram_I).

He was the king of neighboring Phoenicia who helped King Solomon build the First Temple in Jerusalem. So ... nice guy.

I wouldn't say he's of massive significance to Judaism today, but he's a good guy in the Bible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 3 week later my son will born and I decidide to named him Hiram. thanks again